# Scala Yeild returning Try[Either[]] rather then Either

Tags: scala, try-catch, for-comprehension, either

I am trying to do some handson with scala basic operations and got stuck here in the following sample code

```
  def insuranceRateQuote(a: Int, tickets:Int) : Either[Exception, Double] = {
    // ... something
    Right(Double)
  }

  def parseInsuranceQuoteFromWebForm(age: String, numOfTickets: String)  : Either[Exception, Double]= {
    try{
      val a = Try(age.toInt)
      val tickets = Try(numOfTickets.toInt)

      for{
        aa <- a
        t <- tickets
      } yield insuranceRateQuote(aa,t)        // ERROR HERE
    } catch {
      case _ => Left(new Exception)}
  }
```

The Error I am getting is that it says `found Try[Either[Exception,Double]]`

I am not getting why it is wrapper under Try of Either

PS - This must not be the perfect way to do in scala so feel free to post your sample code :)

Comment: It is quite weird to wrap a **Try** inside a `try`.

Answer (score 4):

The key to understand is that [for-comprehensions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) might transform what is inside the wrapper but will not change the wrapper itself. The reason is because for-comprehension de-sugar to `map`/`flatMap` calls on the wrapper determined in the first step of the chain. For example consider the following snippet

```
val result: Try[Int] = Try(41).map(v => v + 1)
// result: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(42)
```

Note how we transformed the value inside the `Try` wrapper from `41` to `42` however the wrapper remained unchanged. Alternatively we could express the same thing using a for-comprehension

```
val result: Try[Int] = for { v <- Try(41) } yield v + 1
// result: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(42)
```

Note how the effect is exactly the same. Now consider the following for comprehension which chains multiple steps

```
val result: Try[Int] =
  for {
    a <- Try(41)   // first step determines the wrapper for all the other steps
    b <- Try(1)
  } yield a + b
// result: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(42)
```

This expands to

```
val result: Try[Int] =
  Try(41).flatMap { (a: Int) =>
    Try(1).map { (b: Int) => a + b }
  }
// result: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(42)
```

where again we see the result is the same, namely, a value transformed inside the wrapper but wrapper remained untransformed.

Finally consider

```
val result: Try[Either[Exception, Int]] =
  for {
    a <- Try(41)       // first step still determines the top-level wrapper
    b <- Try(1)
  } yield Right(a + b) // here we wrap inside `Either`
// result: scala.util.Try[Either[Exception,Int]] = Success(Right(42))
```

The principle remains the same - we did wrap `a + b` inside `Either` however this does not affect the top-level outer wrapper which is still `Try`.

Comment: I updated my function definition as follows
 `def parseInsuranceQuoteFromWebForm(age: String, numOfTickets: String)  : Try[Either[Exception, Double]]`
Please let me know if this looks good or I can further modify with some scala stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @Ani the best would be to transform the **Either** into a **Try** or _viceversa_, so you end up with just one kind of wrapper. Specially because a **Try** of an **Either** is hard to use and usually doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Mario Galic's answer already explains the problem with your code, but I'd fix it differently.

Two points:

1. `Either[Exception, A]` (or rather, `Either[Throwable, A]`) is kind of equivalent to `Try[A]`, with `Left` taking the role of `Failure` and `Right` the role of `Success`.
2. The outer `try`/`catch` is not useful because the exceptions should be captured by working in `Try`.

So you probably want something like

```
def insuranceRateQuote(a: Int, tickets:Int) : Try[Double] = {
  // ... something
  Success(someDouble)
}

def parseInsuranceQuoteFromWebForm(age: String, numOfTickets: String):  Try[Double] = {
  val a = Try(age.toInt)
  val tickets = Try(numOfTickets.toInt)

  for{
    aa <- a
    t <- tickets
    q <- insuranceRateQuote(aa,t)
  } yield q
}
```

A bit unfortunately, this does a useless `map(q => q)` if you figure out what the comprehension does, so you can write it more directly as

```
a.flatMap(aa => tickets.flatMap(t => insuranceRateQuote(aa,t)))
```